# Compare date() to timestamp PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way that I can compare a day with `date()`on php and `timestamp()` on db like this

example:

`date();` has this value `2021-11-02`

`timestamp()` has this value `2021-11-02 11:00:52`

here's my code

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
$fetch_user_by_number = "SELECT id,transfer_amount,number FROM `transfer_wallet` WHERE `transfer_number`=:number AND `transaction_date` ORDER BY `transaction_date` DESC limit 1";
```

What I am trying to do is create a push notification on my App that whenever a new data arrived at my db i will push notify the user on my application.

I am just kind of lost on the comparison of date stuff. Any logic or idea will be very appreciated . Thank you.

Comment: Where are you using `current_date`? Should be able to use a `like` with an appended wild card, presuming you are using leading 0s as well... or your MySQL and PHP timezones are off? Can you just use MySQL current time?

Comment: will use it here ```WHERE  `transfer_number`=:number AND `transaction_date` >= $current_date ``` and I can't use current_time because I need it to compare it everytime when there's a new data good sir

Comment: In your example `$current_date`,  `2021-11-3`, is greater than`timestamp()`, `2021-11-02 11:00:52`. Also parameterize all parts of query.

Comment: sorry wrong input of example .  It should be `2021-11-02` also . and yeah I will parameterize it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT `id`, `transfer_amount`, `number` 
FROM `transfer_wallet` 
WHERE `transfer_number`= :number 
  AND `transaction_date` >= now() 
ORDER BY `transaction_date` DESC limit 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for these . I'll mark yours as an answer because I have now an Idea . Thank you.